# Don't render abel for id in django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Is it possible not to render the `for` attribute of a `label`?

I want `<label>Text</label>` instead of `<label for="id_i">Text</label>` ?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to manually render the form field: `<label>{{field.label}}</label>` will render the label as you require. See the docs for how to manually render form fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Answer (score 0):

I more flexible solution is to override `id_for_label` in a widget.